# How can I make the 'X' button in a modal popup window redirect to another site

Tags: jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialog-message").css("display", "none");
    $("#uniqueCode").click(function() {
        $("#dialog-message").dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 400,
            height: 250,
            position: {
                my: "center",
                at: "center",
                of: window
            },
            buttons: {
                Ok: {
                    text: "Ok",
                    id: "subBtn",
                    click: function() {
                        window.location.href = "google.com";
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The code above for the modal popup window shows a message to the user, and there's an Ok button at the bottom right hand corner of the popup window. There is also an 'X' button at the top right. When the user clicks the Ok button, they get redirected to another page. Everything works until I found an issue. The issue is when the user clicks the 'X' button on the top right, they don't get redirected. I have tried everything that I thought I could to make it work, but I am still stuck! How can I redirect the user to another site when they click either the 'X' button on the top right or the 'Ok' button on the bottom right? Can somebody help me?

EDIT:

```
<input type="submit" id="uniqueCode" name="submit" value="Submit" />

<div id="dialog-message" title="Reference Return Code">
```

The input button triggers the modal. And the div is for the window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Thanks for the help, guys. But I have solved the issue.

EDIT: I had to "inspect" the page and saw the class id for the button. It's from the framework that I am using and I forgot to check it earlier

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div#dialog-message').on('dialogclose', function(event) {
     window.location.href = "--your URL goes here--";
 }):
```

or

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    resizable: false,
    width: 400,
    height: 140,
    modal: true, 
    buttons: {
        "SUBMIT": function() { 
        $("form").submit();
    },         
    },
    close: function() {
      window.location.href = "--your URL goes here--";
    }
});
```

Comment: I have put the the class or id, and still not working

Comment: Still nothing. I will keep playing with it and see what I can do

Comment: In the fiddle, the ID close button didnt take me anywhere. The button at the bottom redirected me to a 404 :(

Comment: Edited.. sorry my bad..updated now. Try this jsfiddle.net/btfmn8v3/6

Answer (score 0):

Keep that X button inside an anchor tag and give it a id or a class, Select that X anchor tag in DOM. Then you can add an event listener to that button.

Like: 
Lets give your X button an Id of close,
Then,

```js
var x = document.getElementById("close");

x.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var anch = document.getElementById("yourAchorTagId");
    anch.href = "yourDesiredUrl";
});
```

Comment: How can I give the X an id or put inside the anchor tag? I mean, it's not an input button or anything. It's already part of the modal window. im new to jquery, sorry

Comment: @azunyan please post your popup modal html

Comment: Please post your modal's html

Comment: @azunyan - You mean to say default close button of modal, right?

Comment: @Rakshith Yes. I am not sure on how I would ID it or anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('your close button id or class').click(function(){
  window.location.href = "google.com"
})
```

Comment: I have put the the class or id, and still not working

Comment: send me your modal html

Comment: <div id="dialog-message" title="ID">